# I have created a EurekaServer in STS but when I am trying to run it as a SpringBootApplication it is giving UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

Here is the pom.xml

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.0.0
 

com.vipul
EurekaServer
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
EurekaServer
Eureka Server

<java.version>17</java.version>
<spring-cloud.version>2022.0.0-RC2</spring-cloud.version>



org.springframework.cloud
spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>netflix-candidates</id>
        <name>Netflix Candidates</name>
        <url>https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I am getting this error when running EurekaServerApplication

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 60.0
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:855)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:753)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:676)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:634)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
at com.vipul.EurekaServerApplication.main(EurekaServerApplication.java:12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using Spring Boot 3, which requires a JDK17 to run (https://spring.io/blog/2022/11/24/spring-boot-3-0-goes-ga). Please configure your project and your launch config to use Java 17.